sudo apt update returns an network is unreachable and connection refused and failed to fetch
$ sudo apt update
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/apps/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (185.125.190.80). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/drivers/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/patches/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done                        
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/apps/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (185.125.190.80). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/drivers/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/patches/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/stable/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


This question is similar to: Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There seems to be an outage at canonical. Even our build pipelines etc are failing:


I've had the same problem with connecting to repository and it was a simple DNS problem.
after i set DNS to 8.8.8.8 it works well.
